# TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'ConcatV2' Op have types [bool, float32] that don't all match

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to reproduce the notebook for entity recognition using LSTM that i found on this link:
https://medium.com/@rohit.sharma_7010/a-complete-tutorial-for-named-entity-recognition-and-extraction-in-natural-language-processing-71322b6fb090

When I try to train the model I get an error that I cannot understand (I'm quite new to tensorflow). In particular the part of code with the error is this one:

```
from keras.models import Model, Input
from keras.layers import LSTM, Embedding, Dense, TimeDistributed, Dropout, Bidirectional
from keras_contrib.layers import CRF

# Model definition
input = Input(shape=(MAX_LEN,))
model = Embedding(input_dim=n_words+2, output_dim=EMBEDDING, # n_words + 2 (PAD & UNK)
                  input_length=MAX_LEN, mask_zero=True)(input)  # default: 20-dim embedding
model = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True,
                           recurrent_dropout=0.1))(model)  # variational biLSTM
model = TimeDistributed(Dense(50, activation="relu"))(model)  # a dense layer as suggested by neuralNer
crf = CRF(n_tags+1)  # CRF layer, n_tags+1(PAD)
print(model)
out = crf(model)  # output

model = Model(input, out)
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss=crf.loss_function, metrics=[crf.accuracy])

model.summary()
```

The error is on the line

```
out = crf(model)
```

The error that I get is this:

```
TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'ConcatV2' Op have types [bool, float32] that don't all match.
```

Can someone give me an explanation?

Answer (score 9):

I also came across this problem today. what worked for me was to remove `mask_zero=True` from the embedding layer. unfortunately I don't know why this helps.

Comment: I found that this is a problem of the new version of keras. I installed the 2.2.4 version but I don't know how to solve the issue in the latest version

Comment: i'm using keras version 2.3.1. your code works for me after removing the mask flag

Comment: This worked for me as well, but would really like to know why it works, if you have discovered it by now.

Comment: Same issue here and solved by removing the mask_zero. But not sure why. Can anyone help to answer?

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears when you use masking in the embedding layer with **keras_contrib** crf layer:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras-contrib/issues/498

The fix is to enforce dtype in `K.zeros_like` for mask in `keras_contrib/layers/crf.py` as it is done in this pull request:
https://github.com/ashutoshsingh0223/keras-contrib/pull/1

or install directly from **keras_contrib** master branch.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have exactly the same problem but, I had this close error with this code :

```
text, context = preprocessor(inputs=[text_input, context_input])

input_dim = 14
Embedding_dim = 16

text = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim, output_dim = Embedding_dim(text)
text = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64))(text)

x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([text, context])
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)


model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = [text_input, context_input], outputs = [x])
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, rankdir="LR", show_shapes=True)
```

> TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "concatenate_9" (type Concatenate).
> Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'ConcatV2' Op have types [float32, int64] that don't all match.
> Call arguments received by layer "concatenate_9" (type Concatenate):
> • inputs=['tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 128), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1), dtype=int64)']

The simple workaround found on the internet is add tf.cast as below just before the concatenation:

```
    context = tf.cast(context, dtype = tf.float32)
```

Answer (score -1):

because the keras_contrib CRF not support masking，so you need close mask_zero=False

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide an actual example.